# Add operator symbols to matrices in Wolfram

Tags: symbolic, operators

I am working with the matrices of the form $u = \begin{pmatrix}Y &y\\0 & Y\end{pmatrix}$, and I have an operator $a$ such that $au=\begin{pmatrix}Y & ay\\0 & Y\end{pmatrix}$. Since y can be any symbolic variable, I'd like to be able to append the symbol of the operator to the upper-right corner of the matrix.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to create $\LaTeX$ expressions or define a *Mathematica* operator. If the later, do you want `a` be both an operator over a matrix, but just a scalar multiplication if over a symbol? As it stands, it's not clear what you are asking and you risk that your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD). To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well-structured and easy to understand. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).